# Consume AWS SQS and publish to Azure Service Bus

Tags: amazon-sqs, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I need a piece of "cloud glue" to read messages from an AWS SQS queue and push the results into an Azure Service Bus. I like Azure Logic Apps but they do not have an SQS connector. I could hand roll the code in an Azure functions, but are there any prebuilt solutions to consume SQS in the Azure world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Function can't be triggered by SQS either, unless you want to do timer + polling.

The easiest I can come up with is AWS Lambda + SQS trigger + Service Bus SDK to send the message.

Comment: Yeah looking like long polling or lambda. Folks should encourage Logic Apps to build SQS integration - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/14911485-integration-with-aws-services

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom bindings for azure functions. Here is an example of an sqs binding.
https://github.com/laveeshb/azure-function-extensions-net/tree/master/Amazon.SQS

Answer (score 0):

Update Jan 2021 - Hurrah, Microsoft have now released a logic apps connector for SQS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/amazonsqs

Comment: while using it, still we need to set 'How often do you want to check for items', so is it still based on timer + polling?